# Yolov4 Transfer Learning and old Classes

Tags: yolo, transfer-learning, yolov4

I trained a model(by  Transfer Leaning ) on my custom dataset of Pistols and it works fine for detecting pistol but when I run detection on  pic containing car and pistol it detect both as Pistol...I want it to detect only Pistol.
Problem is that it still detect previous classes which were pre-trained (which I don't want to detect).
[Yolo v4 detecting both car and pistol as Gun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcyZi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look at these [previous answers](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63947/image-classification-using-single-class-dataset-using-transfer-learning) on a similar question. The answers are regarding image classification on single class transfer learning, yet you may find it interesting to your problem.